# R - Loop through each row and fill with value from previous row

Tags: r, loops

I'd like to test whether a value from a particular column contains an NA value, and if so, fill that NA space with the value from the previous row. I'm still trying to get the hang of the `apply` family of functions.

E.g. I want to turn this:

```
      Date   Balance
2012-01-01      1000
2012-01-02        NA
2012-01-03        NA
2012-01-04      1200
2012-01-05      1215
2012-01-06        NA
```

into:

```
      Date   Balance
2012-01-01      1000
2012-01-02      1000
2012-01-03      1000
2012-01-04      1200
2012-01-05      1215
2012-01-06      1215
```

Comment: take a look at `na.locf` from zoo package

Comment: Good find @Jilber. The `apply` family wouldn't work well here since the what you want to do to a given value depends on nearby values (i.e., you don't get to use indices in `apply` functions).

Comment: The simplest `base` method would probably be a `for` loop (correct me if I'm wrong): `for (i in 1:length(DF$Balance)) if (is.na(DF$Balance[i])) DF$Balance[i] = DF$Balance[i-1]`

Comment: @SeñorO That for-loop would work for every observation (i) in that specific column (`DF$Balance`), but how would you do it if you wanted it to loop through every column in every row instead of just every row?

Comment: @coip You'd simple have to do two for loops, but at that point you should really just get the zoo package and use `na.locf` as mentioned below, which will automatically take care of all columns for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a task for `na.locf` function from zoo package. See `?na.locf`

Consider `DF` is your data.frame, then:

```
DF <- read.table(text="      Date   Balance
2012-01-01      1000
2012-01-02        NA
2012-01-03        NA
2012-01-04      1200
2012-01-05      1215
2012-01-06        NA", header=TRUE)

library(zoo)
na.locf(DF)
        Date Balance
1 2012-01-01    1000
2 2012-01-02    1000
3 2012-01-03    1000
4 2012-01-04    1200
5 2012-01-05    1215
6 2012-01-06    1215
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `data.table` with `roll = TRUE` also does this nicely!

```
require(data.table)
# convert Date column to date format
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
# keep this, as we'll remove rows with NA to use `roll`
dates   <- df$Date
# remove rows with NA
dt2     <- na.omit(data.table(df))
# set key to Date
setkey(dt2, "Date")
# use dates which has the NA rows that will be filled 
# with value from previous column with roll=T
dt2[J(dates), roll=T]

#          Date Balance
# 1: 2012-01-01    1000
# 2: 2012-01-02    1000
# 3: 2012-01-03    1000
# 4: 2012-01-04    1200
# 5: 2012-01-05    1215
# 6: 2012-01-06    1215
```